# Problema "repaint()" Clase Vista Modelo MVC

Tags: java, mvc, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy implementado una interfaz gráfica siguiendo el patrón modelo-vista-controlador. Las clases de modelo y controlador funcionan correctamente (Si necesitais ver el código de las clases que acabo de nombrar, ponedmelo en un comentario). El problema está en la clase Vista, que es la suguiente:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package patronmvc;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacio
 */
public class Vista extends Canvas  implements Observer{
    private Modelo m;
    private Controlador c;
    public Vista(Modelo m, Controlador c){
        this.c = c;
        this.m = m;
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawLine(m.getCooordenadas(), 10, m.getCooordenadas(), 180);
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Observable obs, Object obj){ 
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Clase Modelo(En esta clase reside la lógica del problema)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package patronmvc;

import java.util.Observable;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacio
 */
public class Modelo extends Observable {
    private int dir;
    private int x = 250;
    public void setDir(int dir){
        this.dir = dir;   
    }
    public int  getCooordenadas(){return x;}
    public void calcularDesplazaminto(){
        if(dir == -1 ){
            if(x > 10)
                x = x - 20;
        }else{
            if(x < 280)
                x = x + 20;
        }
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

}
```

Clase Controlador (GUI)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package patronmvc;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author ignacio
 */
public class Controlador extends JFrame{
    private JButton izq, der;
    private int w = 500, h = 300;
    private JPanel contenedorBotones;
    protected JPanel contenedorLinea;
    private Modelo modelo;
    private Vista vista;
    private Dimension d1, d2;
    private Graphics g;
    public void configurarControlador(){

        d1 = new Dimension(500,200);
        d2 = new Dimension(500, 100);
        izq = new JButton("Mover a la izquierda");
        der = new JButton("Mover a la derecha");
        modelo = new Modelo();
        vista = new Vista(modelo, this);
        modelo.addObserver(vista);
        contenedorBotones = new JPanel();
        contenedorLinea = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
          super.paintComponent(g);
          g.drawLine(250 ,10,250 ,180);
        }
      };

        contenedorBotones.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        contenedorLinea.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        contenedorBotones.setPreferredSize(d2);
        contenedorLinea.setPreferredSize(d1);
        contenedorBotones.add(izq);
        contenedorBotones.add(der);

        izq.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                modelo.setDir(-1);
                modelo.calcularDesplazaminto();
            }
        });
        der.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                modelo.setDir(1);
                modelo.calcularDesplazaminto();
            }
        });
         addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evento){
                switch(evento.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                            modelo.setDir(-1);
                            modelo.calcularDesplazaminto();
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:  
                            modelo.setDir(1);
                            modelo.calcularDesplazaminto();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                });

        add(contenedorLinea);
        add(contenedorBotones);

        setTitle("Movimiento");
        setSize(w,h);
        setResizable(true);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,0,0));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Captura debuggeando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No hace efecto la llamada al "paint()" del "repaint()". La verdad es no entiendo nada, extendiendo la clase Canvas que a su vez extiende a Component. A mi entender, si además sobreescribiendo el método "paint()" debería entrar, pero no lo hace. Para ser más claro, el problema es que el rapaint() no hace ni caso. ¿Alguno sabe cuál es el erro?

Comment: cuando estas usando la funcion update ?

Comment: Cuando la clase observable, modelo, hace la llamada a los métodos: setChanged() y notifyObservers(). Haciendo debug todo va como debe hasta que entra en update() y no ejecuta "repaint()".

Comment: puedes colocar el codigo de todo ello que mencionaste?

Comment: en el paint debes iniciar con borrar todo, y luego debes dibujar lo que gustes

Comment: Ya están incluidas todas la clases, controlador, vista y modelo.

Answer (score 0):

En el metodo paint() debes iniciar limpliando todo el lienzo para que cuando se realice un refresh (update) se dibuje nuevamente, es decir se dibujara todo nuevamente.

para limpiar el lienzo prueba con:

```
g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

o primero fijando un color para luego dibujar un rectangulo:

```
 g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

otra cosa que puedes probar es cambiar de funcion paint a paintComponent

```
@Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
}
```

si eso no funciona prueba con

```
    obs.validate();
    obs.repaint();
```

Comment: Pero aun así, si no limpio la recta ¿No se debería pintar la nueva sobre el lienzo con la anterior vieja, vamos que se fueran acumulando?

Comment: @ignacioaranguren hice algunos cambios en mi respuesta

Comment: No, sé como se tiene que pintar y repintar. Aun así, gracias, pero el problema es que cuando ejecuta la sentencia repaint(), no se ejecuta el paint que he sobreescrito.

Comment: Subo ahora una captura de pantalla para que quede mas claro

Comment: @ignacioaranguren donde esta el metodo run()?